# How to query website from android app?

Tags: android, webview

i am learning android dev...i am facing an issue.i have searched a lot but couldn't find the answer so posting here.

http://cnic.sims.pk/

Above website is a utility.i want to give the input to it from editText field of my app and when i press the submit button it should query the website and then i will display the result in a WebView. Right now i am displaying whole thing in a WebView that is input and result.

Can any one help me how to implement this...i just want a hint....Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

@Rashid Hussain i believe you need to show url when you click submit button am i right? if so add a textfield and button to layout and add onClick to submit button